# Объединение результатов т-критерия в таблицу

Tags: python

Рассчитываю т-критерий методом `scipy.stats.ttest_ind`. Для каждого показателя (у меня их 7 по столбцам) у меня рассчитываются отличия для подвыборок мужчин и женщин.
Я хочу это объединить в таблицу, чтоб оно выплевывалось не в куче или не отдельного для конкретно указанного показателя.

```
ttest = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(men, women)
itog = pd.DataFrame({"statistic":[ttest[0]],
                       "pvalue": [ttest[1]],
                       "значимость": ['True' if ttest[1] >= 0.05 else 'False']})
```

Но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой ValueError: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Вероятно, мои результаты (на самом деле выплевываемые прямым подсчетом для датафрейма в виде

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=array([ 0.05133366,  2.08921468,  0.53197364, -1.52560193,  3.60045126,
        1.62095854,  3.90005821]), pvalue=array([9.59113294e-01, 3.80132297e-02, 5.95362479e-01, 1.28763189e-01,
       4.04850724e-04, 1.06676229e-01, 1.33116661e-04]))
```

нужно "расшить", прежде чем компоновать в таблицу. Как мне обойти эту ошибку? Предпочитаемый итог, к которому стремлюсь, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
ttest = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(men, women)
itog = pd.DataFrame({"statistic": ttest[0],
                       "pvalue": ttest[1],
                       "значимость": ttest[1] >= 0.05})
```

Пояснение. Код `ttest[1] >= 0.05` порождает `Pandas.Series` с булевским вектором значений, и когда вы пытаетесь его методами питона проверить через `if` `Pandas.Series` на истинность - возникает ошибка - питон не понимает, что ему делать с массивом булевых значений, истинно оно или ложно - непонятно. А вот `Pandas` прекрасно знает, как обработать `Pandas.Series`, чтобы сделать из него колонку в `DataFrame` - он возьмёт из него значения, а индекс отбросит.

Или можно сделать так, если вам так более понятно, и если вам нужны именно строковые `True` и `False`, а не булевские. Т.е. применить `тернарный if` нужно **к каждому элементу массива**:

```
"значимость": ['True' if t >= 0.05 else 'False' for t in ttest[1]]
```

P.S. Обратите внимание, что я ещё убрал квадратные скобки, в которые вы взяли значения первых двух колонок. У вас так получится, что все значения массива попадут в одну ячейку `DataFrame`-а.

Comment: Почему-то получаю ошибку ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: @IoIo А квадратные скобки убрали для значений первых двух колонок, как у меня в коде? А то у вас там получается список из одного элемента, в котором лежит массив, конечно, длина не совпадёт в результате.

Comment: Точно! Все получилось, спасибо большое